# Can't install simple .inf file

Tags: device-driver, windows-7-x64, inf

Im trying to install a device driver using the "Add Hardware" wizard and I keep getting the following error after selecting the .inf file I am trying to install:

> The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software
>   driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it
>   is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems.

The following is the contents of my driver file.

device.inf:

```
[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
CatalogFile.NTx86=mox86.cat
CatalogFile.NTIA64=moia64.cat
CatalogFile.NTAMD64=moamd64.cat
Class=HIDClass
ClassGuid={745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}
Provider=%Vendor%
DriverVer=03/19/2013,6.1.7601.17515

[ControlFlags]
ExcludeFromSelect = *

[Manufacturer]
%Vendorr% = HTPI,NTx86,NTamd64,NTia64

[HTPI.NTx86]
%USB\VID_0D8C&PID_0176&MI_00.DeviceDesc% = Device_Inst.NTx86,, USB\VID_0D8C&PID_0176&MI_00

[HTPI.NTamd64]
%USB\VID_0D8C&PID_0176&MI_00.DeviceDesc% = Device_Inst.NTamd64,, USB\VID_0D8C&PID_0176&MI_00

[HTPI.NTia64]
%USB\VID_0D8C&PID_0176&MI_00.DeviceDesc% = Device_Inst.NTia64,, USB\VID_0D8C&PID_0176&MI_00

[Device_Inst.NTx86]
Include=input.inf
Needs=HID_Inst.NT

[Device_Inst.NTamd64]
Include=input.inf
Needs=HID_Inst.NT

[Device_Inst.NTia64]
Include=input.inf
Needs=HID_Inst.NT

[Strings]
Vendor = "Mo"
USB\VID_0D8C&PID_0176&MI_00.DeviceDesc = "Mo's Device"
```

I believe that the driver file does in fact work with x64 based systems. I created the mox86.cat and moamd64.cat catalog files and I have test signed them and installed the certificate on my computer. With sign tool I verified that both mox86.cat and moamd64 were signed.

Also trying to install with DevCon gives me an error. This is the command I am using to install vai DevCon:

```
devcon install c:\devicedriver\driver\device.inf "USB\VID_0D8C&PID_0176&MI_03"
```

Anyone know where I have gone wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the wrong class

```
Class=HIDClass 
ClassGuid={745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}
```

But my device was `Class=Media`.